# Meteor-Angular tutorial: bad formatting in HTML template, for copy/paste code

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Working through the [meteor-angular tutorial, at step 2](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates) I create the angular template `todos-list.ng.html`:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <li>{{task.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and get this result

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While building the application:
   todos-list.ng.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

since this is copy-and-paste, this puzzles me. I don't see anything to account for it, does anyone else have any ideas?

**Update**

Here are the other files. The previous sub-steps worked, if that's any help.  I'm confident it's something silly, but I sure don't see what,

simple-todos-angular.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Charlie's Todo List with Angular.js</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="simple-todos"
      ng-include="'todos-list.ng.html'"
      ng-controller="TodosListCtrl">
</body>
```

simple-todos-angular.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // This code only runs on the client
  angular.module('simple-todos',['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('simple-todos').controller('TodosListCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

      $scope.tasks = [
        { text: 'This is task 1' },
        { text: 'This is task 2' },
        { text: 'This is task 3' }
      ];

  }]);
}
```

simple-todos-angular.css:

```
/* CSS declarations go here */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #315481;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #315481, #918e82 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

header {
  background: #d2edf4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0edf5, #e1e5f0 100%);
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#login-buttons {
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

form {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  position: relative;
}

.new-task input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 80px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.new-task input:focus{
  outline: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: #eee solid 1px;
}

li .text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

li.checked {
  color: #888;
}

li.checked .text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li.private {
  background: #eee;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

header .hide-completed {
  float: right;
}

.toggle-private {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  li {
    padding: 12px 15px;
  }

  .search {
    width: 150px;
    clear: both;
  }

  .new-task input {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

/* CSS declarations go here */
```

Comment: Double check your work for steps 2.2, 2.3, and 2.4.  Did you replace the entire file contents for 2.2 and 2.3?  I just followed the steps through 2.4 and it works as expected.  Does your todos-list.ng.html have exactly what you've shown in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you've missed the step at the top of the page - adding the `urigo:angular` package. Run the following from the terminal (in your meteor project directory):

`meteor add angular`

(edit: was previously `meteor add urigo:angular` but as stated in the comments that package has now been deprecated).

Without it, Meteor would try to parse *.ng.html as normal html files. It's failing because it can't find one of the following:

- `<head>`
- `<body>`
- `<template name="X">`

Comment: I get message: "urigo:angular: Deprecated: use the official `angular` package instead!"

Comment: @GlebSvechnikov do `meteor add angular` then I guess. Meteor 1.2 recently added support for angular and react so I guess this is why urigo's package is deprecated.